# NPM / typescript / node.js Export functions from non module package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, package.json, npm-package

I have 2 different projects which have some common functions.

- Project 1 : Authentication + api 1 (express but not important)
- Project 2 : Api 2 (express)

Is it possible to export Authentication function from Project 1 and use it in Project 2 ?

I tried to make a basic package but : If the Projet 1 is a module, I can't start api. If it's not, I can't import function in Project 2

Basically I want something like :

Project 1 :

- function.ts

```
export default function foo() {
   if (Html.isProgrammingLanguage()) return 'Boooooo';
   return 'Aha yes';
}
```

- index.ts

```
import foo from './function.ts';
// express things
router.use('/', () => {
   foo();
});
```

Project 2 :

- package.json

```
{
   "dependencies": {
      "project1": "<my git link>"
   }
}
```

- index.ts

```
import foo from 'project1';

// other express things

router.use('/', () => {
   foo();
});
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: How about sperating the Authentication function into a third project and import into both?

Comment: @ChengDicky I thought about it but it force me to separate the Sequelize part and the api for 1 authentication function, i find this solution too heavy for this little problem. Before I find another solution I just call the authentication api by http request, it's not most efficient but it work !